# Quotation Marks Disappear After Font Change

Tags: punctuation

After a font change, proper curly quotes disappear under XeLaTex (and LuaLaTex)in the area after the change, but remain properly generated in the area before the change. I can't figure out why. Both fonts have proper curly quotes in their glyph set. I've tried other secondary fonts with the same results. Here's a MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=5in:8in,DIV=12]{scrbook} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Bembo Std}



\begin{document}


 ``You see, Lena, this is a good place because the truck drivers eat    here. They always know where the best food is.''

 \newfontfamily\myfont{Alegreya}
\begingroup
\myfont
and began what he himself has termed a ``fanatical devotion'' to  swimming.
\endgroup


\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing the Ligatures option: `\newfontfamily\myfont{Alegreya}[Ligatures=TeX]`.

Comment: I didn't realize the word "TeX" was case sensitive. Otherwise it throws the following error: LaTeX error: "kernel/key-choice unknown"
Key 'fontspec/Ligatures' accepts only a fixed set of choices. 
See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information. 
For immediate help type H return.


The key 'fontspec/Ligatures' only accepts predefined values, and 'Tex' is not one of these.

Comment: Please make this an answer since the text now compiles properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `Ligatures` option:

```
\newfontfamily\myfont{Alegreya}[Ligatures=TeX]
```